# Get least recently rented movies in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

So imagine you have the following two tables:

```
CREATE movies (
    id int,
    name varchar(255),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE movieRentals (
    id int,
    movie_id int,
    customer varchar(255),
    dateRented datetime,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
);
```

With SQL directly, I'd approach this query as:

```
(
    SELECT movie_id, count(movie_id) AS rent_count
    FROM movieRentals
    WHERE  dateRented > [TIME_ARG_HERE]
    GROUP BY movie_id
)
UNION
(
    SELECT id AS movie_id, 0 AS rent_count
    FROM movie
    WHERE movie_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT movie_id
        FROM movieRentals
        WHERE dateRented > [TIME_ARG_HERE]
        GROUP BY movie_id
    )
)
```

(Get a count of all movie rentals, by id, since a given date)

Obviously the Django version of these tables are simple models:

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class MovieRentals(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dateRented = models.DateTimeField()
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies)
```

However, translating this to an equivalent query appears to be difficult:

```
timeArg = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(7,0)
queryset = models.MovieRentals.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.filter(dateRented__gte=timeArg)
queryset = queryset.annotate(rent_count=Count('movies'))

querysetTwo = models.Movies.objects.all()
querysetTwo = querysetTwo.filter(~Q(id__in=[val["movie_id"] for val in queryset.values("movie_id")]))
# Somehow need to set the 0 count. For now force it with Extra:
querysetTwo.extra(select={"rent_count": "SELECT 0 AS rent_count FROM app_movies LIMIT 1"})

# Now union these - for some reason this doesn't work:
# return querysetOne | querysetTwo
# so instead
set1List = [_getMinimalDict(model) for model in queryset]
# Where getMinimalDict just extracts the values I am interested in.
set2List = [_getMinimalDict(model) for model in querysetTwo]
return sorted(set1List + set2List, key=lambda x: x['rent_count'])
```

However, while this method seems to work, it is incredibly slow. Is there a better way I am missing?

Comment: What is your SQL query supposed to do? It looks to me like it returns all of the movies rented after [TIME ARG HERE], with their rental counts since that date, as well as *one* movie which hasn't been rented since that time.

Comment: Sorry, never saw this. LIMIT 1 should definitely be removed, I don't know what I was thinking. Otherwise, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With straight SQL, this would be much easier expressed like this:

```
SELECT movie.id, count(movieRentals.id) as rent_count
FROM movie
LEFT JOIN movieRentals ON (movieRentals.movie_id = movie.id AND dateRented > [TIME_ARG_HERE])
GROUP BY movie.id
```

The left join will produce a single row for each movie unrented since [TIME_ARG_HERE], but in those rows, the movieRentals.id column will be NULL.

Then, `COUNT(movieRentals.id)` will count all of the rentals where they exist, and return 0 if there was only the NULL value.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something obvious. Why wouldn't the following work:

```
queryset = models.MovieRentals.filter(dateRented__gte=timeArg).values('movies').annotate(Count('movies')).aggregate(Min('movies__count'))
```

Also, clauses can be chained (as shown in the code above), so there is no reason to constantly set a `queryset` variable to the intermediate querysets.

Comment: The problem with just doing a Min('movies__count') is it will leave us with only movies rented once or more - anything not rented at all will be filted. out.